# Get all opened websites from Chrome in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, url

I am on Windows 8.1, Python 3.6.

Is it possible to get all currently open websites in the Latest version Of Chrome and save the websites to a text file in `D:/`.

I tried opening file:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Tabs
```

But I receive an error saying that the file is opened in another program.
There is another file named `History` that contains URLs that are opened but it also contain characters like `NULL`.

I tried reading the file in python but I received **UndicodeDecodeError***(Not sure About This Word)*.
then I tried opening file by the following code:

```
with open('C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History',"r+",encoding='latin') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data)
```

And it worked. But I got 1 or 2 URLs while in the text file, there were no URLs.

Maybe there's another way something like importing a module.
Something like:

```
import chrome
url = chrome.get_url()
print(url)
```

Maybe `selenium` can also do this. But I don't know how.
Maybe there's another way to read the file with all links in python.

Want I want with it is that it detect websites opened, if **mywebsite.com** is opened for more than 10 minutes, it will automatically be blocked. The system has its own file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

It will add the following at the end:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mywebsite.com
```

And the website will no longer be available to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this methodology to store the tab data and manipulate it:

```
windows = driver.window_handles
```

You can store the windows using the above method.

```
current_window = driver.current_window_handle
```

This method will give you the current window that is being handled. You can go through the list 'windows' and check if it is current_window to navigate between the tabs.

```
driver.switch_to.window(windows[5])
```

This method will switch to a desired tab but I assume you already have it.

Now how do you store the time spent after the tabs are opened?
There are two ways to do it:

1. Internally, by referring to a pandas dataframe or list
2. Reading and writing to a file.

First you need to import the 'time' library inside the script

```
current_time=time.time()
```

current_time is an int representation of the current time. It's a linux timestamp.

In either one of these scenarios, you will need a structure such as this:

```
data=[]
for i in range(0,len(windows)):
    data.append([  windows[i] , time.time() ])
```

This will give a structure as below:

```
    [[window[0],1234564879],
    [window[1],1234567896],...]
```

Here's the thing you miss:

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
   if time.time()-data[i][1] > 600  # If new timestamp minus the old one is bigger than 600 seconds
       driver.switch_to(data[i][0])
       driver.close()
```

My personal advice is that you start with stable API services to get whatever data you want instead of selenium. I would recommend [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com) since I work there. It has variety of scrapers including a google results scraper, and it has 5000 free calls for new accounts.